# showing a status message in R

Tags: r, message, status, statusbar

I'd like to write a function that presents to the user a status message that shows something like the time, the percent complete, and the current status of a process. I can handle assembling the message, but I'd like to do something other than just print to the console and have it scroll up, one message after the other. I'd really like the message to change without scrolling like `message()` and without any graphics. Is this possible with R?

Comment: "This is R. There is no if. Only how." --Simon Blomberg

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  Sys.sleep(0.2)
  # Dirk says using cat() like this is naughty ;-)
  #cat(i,"\r")
  # So you can use message() like this, thanks to Sharpie's
  # comment to use appendLF=FALSE.
  message(i,"\r",appendLF=FALSE)
  flush.console()
}
```

Comment: Don't use `cat()`, use `message()` (which can be suppressed) as eg discussed on a R-bloggers post today arguing gripes with `cat()`.

Comment: @Dirk: It would have to be `message(..., appendLF = FALSE)`---otherwise scrolling messages would appear on the console which the OP specifically wanted to avoid.

Comment: @Dirk replacing `cat()` with `message()` adds a newline with each update.  Do you have to do something extra to prevent the newline?  FWIW, `txtProgressBar` uses `cat()`.

Comment: Hmpf. Thanks guys.  Guess not in that case *but as a general features it is lovely* to be able to suppress line noise, e.g. in scripts via littler or Rscript.

Comment: @Dirk: Sorry, I had to update my comment after I RTFM. Totally possible to substitute `message()` for `cat()` if the proper arguments are provided.

Comment: Glad someone read the post.  Shameless self promotion: http://4dpiecharts.com/2011/01/20/bad-kitty/

Answer (score 19):

The `utils` package contains the `txtProgressBar` and functions for updating it which can be used to show the percent complete of a process.

See the `up1`, `up2` and `up3` functions that are created during a call to `txtProgressBar` for examples of how updates are handled without scrolling the console.

Comment: That's fantastic! You can also create and set your own update function via: `tpb <- txtProgressBar(...); myUpFun <- function(value) {...}; tpb$up <- myUpFun`.  Then you can write an update function using `message()` so Dirk can suppress the noise. ;-)

Comment: @Joshua: Good observation!  When I was pondering creating a custom update function, I was envisioning having to copy and re-write `txtProgressBar()` in order to implement it.

Comment: There's also `plyr::progress_text`. It's a simple wrapper for `txtProgressBar`, though...

Answer (score 15):

Here's some bling bling. From `?tcltk::tkProgressBar`.

```
pb <- tkProgressBar("test progress bar", "Some information in %",
        0, 100, 50)
Sys.sleep(0.5)
u <- c(0, sort(runif(20, 0 ,100)), 100)
for(i in u) {
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    info <- sprintf("%d%% done", round(i))
    setTkProgressBar(pb, i, sprintf("test (%s)", info), info)
}
Sys.sleep(5)
close(pb)
```

[image]

Comment: that's really cool to have for completeness, but my current need is for a text only solution.

Comment: I didn't read your question to the end when tcltk popped up. It was an impulse answer, for which I apologize. Perhaps you from the future will need it some day.

Comment: +1 Fantastic.  It even inspires me to learn a bit about TclTk.

Answer (score 8):

There may be more elegant ways to do this, but this could do it:

```
test.message <- function() {
  for (i in 1:9){
    cat(i)
    Sys.sleep(1)
    cat("\b")
  }

}
```

If you're automatically generating your message, you'll need to calculate how many \b characters to output to back up the correct amount, but that's pretty straightforward.