# Prevent Rstudio console from showing script commands

Tags: r, rstudio

I am running hundreds of code lines from a `script.R` using `Rstudio`, but what  annoys me a bit compared to `Matlab` is that the `Rstudio` console keeps *mechanically* showing the each `command line` from my script file. Is there a way to prevent this from occuring?

The *frustrating* part comes, when one uses `sprintf()` for instance, to the extent that command lines from the script file get mixed up with `sprintf()` in the console.

Best,

Comment: Aren't there two options when sourcing the script: Source and Source with Echo? It sounds like you are clicking Source with Echo. I always click on plain Source and don't see the script lines.

Comment: @drhagen: thx for highlighting on the differences with `Echo`, although I am not clicking of any of them. while writing the script, i was executing it using `ctrl +a`, then `f5`. Based on your feedback, when i click on plain `Source`, the issue is that `sprintf()` does not show up in the console.

Comment: That is because sprintf does not print to the command line; it creates a string. If you run things line by line, the REPL will print bare values for you for convenience (just like a bare `1+1`), but sourcing the script doesn't do this, it just discards them. Put a `print()` around those `sprintf`s.

Comment: @drhagen No, `print` isn’t really the tool for this either — `message` is.

Comment: @drhagen: thx.that solves my issue. best.

Answer (score 17):

Run your code with `ctrl+shift+S` . Or go to source on top right of your `script.R` and then run just `Source` and not `Source with echo`. And, as for your requirement for printing  @Konrad Rudolph suggestion of using message `message("%f", pi)` is the best solution .

If printing the message is intended to track the status of your code here are  some helpful solutions [showing a status message in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754996/showing-a-status-message-in-r)

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to run `script.R` try using the `source` function instead.

```
source("script.R") # assuming script.R is in your working directory.
```

This function will run the script without showing everything in the command line.

Comment: thx. unfortunately `source("path/script.R")` prevents `sprintf()` from being disclosed in the console.

Comment: @owner That’s intentional, `sprintf` *isn’t supposed* to print to the console. Use `message` instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: i usually use `sprintf()` to print `strings` to console at least in `Matlab`. fyi: `message()` works too, although a confusion could be made (in apprearance) with R `default warnings` message. Best,

Comment: @owner For the record, `sprintf` doesn't print strings, `fprintf` does that, but leaving the semicolon off a line in Matlab will print anything on that line, but whatever works for you.

Comment: @owner Well you’re doing it wrong. It happens to work under specific circumstances but as you’re seeing here, it doesn’t work reliably. Incidentally, the same is true for Matlab. `sprintf`, despite its name, is for string *formatting*, not for printing.

Answer (score 4):

Like Matlab's `sprintf`, R's `sprintf` only creates a string, it doesn't print it to the output.* You have to explicitly call the `print` function to see anything:

```
print(sprintf("%f", pi)) # prints
```

A plain `sprintf` officially creates a string and then discards it because it wasn't saved to a variable:

```
sprintf("%f", pi) # does nothing
```

However, this sort of worked for you because the REPL (the command line that runs R code one line at a time) disobeys the directive to discard values that aren't saved to variables, but instead prints them. This is a convenience thing to make it easier to work at the command line. You can type `1+1` and get it to print `2` even though an R script would normally discard the value silently.

Other functions that print text to the console are `cat` and `message`, which are each slightly different. See their help files for usage.

<sub>* Technically, Matlab will print the value of any statement that isn't terminated by a `;`, including strings. So without a semicolon, the string that results from `sprintf` can get printed though it's not being done by `sprintf` directly, but by the generic print-all-the-things behavior of Matlab. In my opinion, this is a weird feature.</sub>

Comment: test  this in `Matlab`: `sprintf('invalidate misunderstanding')` and please update your assertion.

Comment: @owner Test this in Matlab: `1 + 2`. Then test `'invalidate misunderstanding'`. You will see that it *also* prints something. Yet clearly neither `1 + 2` nor `'invalidate misunderstanding'` are print statements. The same is true for `sprintf`.

Answer (score 2):

An update to this which may be helpful for future searches, if you are using the '**source**' button in Rstudio (top right hand corner of the script editor window) it will default to '**source**' or '**source with echo**' depending on the last keyboard source input it received.

So, if you click '**ctrl+shift+enter**', it will always '**source with echo**' each subsequent time you use the 'source' button (i.e. print all script commands to the console).

If you click '**ctrl+shift+s**' then it will simply source each time you subsequently use the '**source**' button (i.e. not print the script commands to the console).

Answer (score 1):

just enclose between () the code line  you want supress from console:

```
1+1
output looks:
> 1+1
[1] 2

(1+1)
output looks:
> [1] 2
```

Comment: It simply does not work in RStudio