# R Shiny app progress Indicator for loading data

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Shiny is our internal BI tool. For our Shiny apps, we load data before shinyServer running:

```
load("afterProcessedData.RData")
# or dt = fread("afterProcessedData.csv")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){ ...
```

However, some of apps are loading big files and they take up to 30s to load up. Many users, when they open a page, don't know whether the page is broken since it is stuck when it is loading. They may close it or click filters, which may cause an error. In this case, a progress bar will be very helpful. I notice `withProgress()` may help but it has to be inside `reactive()` or `renderXx()`.

One way I can do is to have `laod()` warpped with `reactive()` inside the `shinyServer(function(input, output, session){` but my concern is it will slower the performance. And my users very care about the responsive performance.

Any suggestions for this situation?

Edit: I guess there is not an easy way to do this. I have another thought. Maybe I can show a text on the screen saying 'the data is loading', but I have to make it disappear after the first table gets show up. However, I don't know how to set up the condition. Below is my code showing first table:

```
dashboardBody(
fluidRow( 
  tabBox(width = 12,
         tabPanel("Summary",
                  dataTableOutput("data1")),
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Curious, why `withProgress()` inside a `reactive ()` or `render()` a problem ? . Even though, I am not happy with the kind status bar it displays, but it works OK for me when I wrap `withProgress` in all my `render()` functions .

Comment: Additionally, how about wrap your data loading functions with examples shown in these [SO solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754996/showing-a-status-message-in-r), and then `render` that out on Shiny `withProgress()` ?

Comment: This works for me.  `output$Ref_output <- DT::renderDataTable(withProgress(
    message = 'Processing the query', value = 5, expr = {
      DT::datatable(reference.table(),
                    selection = 'multiple')`  With some changes to CSS file the progress bar is thicker and in red color  than default one.

Comment: @user5249203 thanks for your answer. My concern of having `load()` in the `reactive()` is that it will slow down the performance since each change will call a `load()`. The second solution with `SO solutions` somehow makes `load()` 3 times longer, which will be blamed by clients.

Comment: If this load is in a global variable then why should it `load` at every session? for everything else you can and should use `withProgress()` also desable buttons while people wait with `shinyjs` package so they dont click on anything until its fully loaded

Answer (score 5):

Even though I am still interested in knowing how to add process bar for `load()`, I have implemented the alternative solution, which is good for now. It has a text saying 'the data is loading...' on the page, and it will disappear after first table shows up.

```
#server.R   firstData is a reactive function to get the data for 1st table
  output$firstTable = reactive({
return(is.null(firstData()))
})
#ui.R
      conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.firstTable",
    box(width = 12,
           h1("The data is loading...")
        )
  )
```

Comment: New aspects. Instead of loading the complete `.rdata`, you can save each object and read them separately. It is efficient and faster. Check `readRDS` . Now, there is an easy way to achieve spinner or likewise in Rshiny . `DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 'table')%>% withSpinner()`

Answer (score 3):

To reference the intriguing note from @user5249203 , `withSpinner()` looks to be a useful option for this functionality and is a part of the [`shinycssloaders`](https://github.com/andrewsali/shinycssloaders) package.  I have not used myself, but it is definitely an intriguing package that happens to be on CRAN and to have some nice examples: https://andrewsali.shinyapps.io/example/